# Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly [InnoDB]

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am facing the following error when i try to restart the MySQL service after an unexpected shutdown of the database server last night.

> Could not start the MySQL service on Local Computer.
>   Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

When i check the .err log file under MySql data folder, the log details are as per below.

---

> InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 804 2135184621
>   150513 12:20:39  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
>   InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>   InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
>   InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
>   InnoDB: buffer...
>   InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 804 2136195241
>   150513 12:20:50  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
>   InnoDB: Progress in percents: 0 1 2 3 150513 12:20:50  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2412 in file .\rem\rem0rec.c line 337
>   InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
>   InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http:// bugs.mysql.com.
>   InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
>   InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
>   InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
>   InnoDB: http:// dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/forcing-recovery.html
>   InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
>   150513 12:20:51 - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
>   This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
>   or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
>   or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
>   We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help diagnose
>   the problem, but since we have already crashed, something is definitely wrong
>   and this may fail.
>   
>   key_buffer_size=135266304
>   read_buffer_size=65536
>   max_used_connections=0
>   max_threads=400
>   threads_connected=0
>   It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
>   key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 262617 K
>   bytes of memory
>   Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
>   
>   thd: 0x0
>   Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
>   where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
>   terribly wrong...
>   InnoDB: Thread 164 stopped in file .\os\os0sync.c line 391
>   0070A1A8    mysqld.exe!rec_get_offsets_func()[rem0rec.c:337]
>   0071B498    mysqld.exe!page_cur_parse_insert_rec()[page0cur.c:798]
>   0071512F    mysqld.exe!recv_parse_or_apply_log_rec_body()[log0recv.c:814]
>   00715CF1    mysqld.exe!recv_recover_page()[log0recv.c:1294]
>   006EBE0F    mysqld.exe!buf_page_io_complete()[buf0buf.c:2033]
>   006E4472    mysqld.exe!fil_aio_wait()[fil0fil.c:4273]
>   006BCDCD    mysqld.exe!io_handler_thread()[srv0start.c:437]
>   77E6482F    kernel32.dll!GetModuleHandleA()
>   The manual page at http:// dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
>   information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

---

Error log show in Event Viewer:

> An unhandled win32 exception occurred in mysqld.exe [1200]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: Debugger could not be started because no user is logged on.

---

```
MySQL version: 5.1<br>
Table Type: InnoDB<br>
ibdata1 Size: 28GB
```

There are no SQL dump backup files for the tables made and there is only the SQL physical data files. I am desperately needed to restore the data of these and bring the website back to online.

Please help.

Comment: This may be useful for you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug within MySQL 5.1 as mentioned within a few bug docs below.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44416
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45844

I have updated the MySQL version to the latest (5.1.73) and then force recovery the InnoDB at level 6 (can only be started at this level for my case). After that, i can proceed with mysqldump.

Answer (score 0):

setting file my.ini 
change or add setting

### innodb_flush_method=normal

restart service mysql